# How to subset and eliminate rows by condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that has many columns: among them AMS card number, registration date, and first purchase date. The data has duplicates for a large number of AMS card numbers. The final dataset needs to be unique on card number. I need to keep the rows in the dataset corresponding to the latest registration date and earliest first purchase date and this is how I've done it. I'm pretty sure it works, but it's too slow, since the dataset has over 1 million rows. In the grand scheme of python and pandas this is not an exorbitant number, which is why I'm certain my algorithm is poor and needs to be rewritten. I'm new to Pandas and fairly new to Python.

```
amsset = set(df["AMS Card"]) #capture all unique AMS numbers for each in amsset:
samecarddf = df.loc[df["AMS Card"] == each] #put all rows of df with same ams numbers in samecarddf 
lensamecarddf = len(samecarddf)
if lensamecarddf > 1: #if there is more than one row with the same ams number in samecarddf
   latestreg = samecarddf['Customer Reg Date'].max() #find the latest registration date
   samecarddf = samecarddf.loc[samecarddf['Customer Reg Date'] == latestreg] #keep the rows with the latest registration date
   earliestpur = samecarddf['Customer First Purchase Date'].min() #find earliest first purchase date
   samecarddf = samecarddf.loc[samecarddf["Customer First Purchase Date"] == earliestpur] #keep the rows with the earliest first purchase date
dffinal = dffinal.append(samecarddf).drop_duplicates() #put all rows with 1 ams or those with latest registration and earliest first purchase and drop any remaining duplicates
```

Comment: You need to provide a short meaningful example of data, the question is currently in very unclear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
# Update df to contain only unique `AMS Card` values, 
# and in case of duplicates, choose the row with latest `Customer Reg Date` and
# (among duplicates thereof) earliest `Customer First Purchase Date`.

dffinal = ( df
    .sort_values(['AMS Card', 'Customer Reg Date', 'Customer First Purchase Date'], ascending=[True, False, True])
    .drop_duplicates(['AMS Card'])
    .drop_duplicates(['AMS Card', 'Customer Reg Date']) )
```

Sample input:

```
   AMS Card Customer Reg Date Customer First Purchase Date  some_data
0         1        2020-01-01                   2021-01-01          1
1         2        2020-01-01                   2021-02-01          2
2         2        2020-01-01                   2021-03-01          3
3         3        2020-01-01                   2021-04-01          4
4         3        2020-02-01                   2021-05-01          5
5         3        2020-02-01                   2021-06-01          6
```

Output:

```
   AMS Card Customer Reg Date Customer First Purchase Date  some_data
0         1        2020-01-01                   2021-01-01          1
1         2        2020-01-01                   2021-02-01          2
4         3        2020-02-01                   2021-05-01          5
```

As an alternative, the sorting can be split into two parts (so that we sort on `Customer First Purchase Date` only after removing duplicates of `Customer Reg Date`):

```py
dffinal = ( df
    .sort_values(['AMS Card', 'Customer Reg Date'], ascending=[True, False])
    .drop_duplicates(['AMS Card'])
    .sort_values(['AMS Card', 'Customer First Purchase Date'], ascending=[True, True])
    .drop_duplicates(['AMS Card', 'Customer Reg Date']) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It's not clear to me why in your first method you would need the second drop_duplicates.  If you have sorted the data correctly, wouldn't the first drop_duplicates only leave one row for every ams number (the one with the latest registration date and earliest first purchase date), assuming it drops duplicates from the end.